# Use of a user defined section name [ __attribute__((section("name")) ]

Tags: linux, linker, compiler

I do have some doubts about `__attribute__((section("name"))` .What is the real use of defining a user defined .section? Is there any examples to shows how it is useful?

Comment: You might want to clarify if the question is directed at e.g. linux kernel code, otherwise it's a question more suited for stackoverflow

Comment: There are [quite a few examples on sources.debian.org](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=attribute__.*section&literal=0) (but that doesn’t explain why it’s useful).

Comment: @Torin, I believe this is allowed in both kernel and user space code. If I understand correctly in kernel code, a whole section can be loaded and unloaded/destroyed from memory when not in use. This is one of the uses(?) . Or is there an another use with section?

Comment: This question with same topic is answered in stackoverflow. Thanks.